# Is 待在家就是吃饭睡觉 grammatically correct?

Tags: sentence-structure

> 待在家就是吃饭睡觉

待在家 是 吃饭
`Staying at home is eating and sleeping` sounds not good.

Comment: 就是 - only is, or merely is. "Staying at home only is eating and sleeping", or "Staying at home is eating and sleeping only", both are fine. Yes, without 就, it is not a good sentence.

Comment: “待在家不是吃饭就是睡觉” is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is right in spoken Chinese.**

Actually, it is a *省略句*. You can easily find that there seems to be not a subject in this sentence. **"待在家" cannot be explained as the subject** because it is not eating or sleeping(the object). As we know, the object is usually "the receiver of a certain action(the verb)". It has something to do with the subject. But if we think "待在家" is the subject, it will be very strange because 吃饭 and 睡觉 must be done by humans or animals. So, where is the subject?

**The subject is omitted.**

The sentence sounds like a critique. We can add "你"(something else is OK) as the subject into the sentence.

```
你呆在家就是吃饭睡觉。
```

It seems that this sentence can be divided into two sentences that have something to do.

```
你待在家。你吃饭睡觉。
```

Because these two sentences have a relationship, so we can add a pair of 连词.

```
你只要待在家，就是吃饭睡觉。
```

Translation:

```
As long as you stay at home, you just eat and sleep.
```

Wait, is 是 a verb here? **The answer is negative.** In my opinion, "就" and it together is just one word, meaning "just". If it is a verb, the sentence is wrong because "你是吃饭睡觉" is incorrect.

This sentence structure is widely used in spoken Chinese, but I do not recommend you to use it in formal written Chinese articles.

Answer (score 1):

Think your sentence is fine.

Could write:

待在家里就只是吃饭、睡觉。
Staying at home, all I do is sleep and eat. (I am extremely boring, zero interests)

Apparently, some part or parts of China, 就 is used for 都。